# Synchronize slider and carousel for a collection in magento

Tags: jquery, html, magento, slider, carousel

I don't have much experience in sliders and callbacks, I am working on a magneto project, which demands a collection of products on homepage, which will be shown through a slider and a carousel. 
I have already set the carousel and slider on its place but I want to change the carousel as the slide change. You can understand the situation well through this image.

[This slider and Carousel will be on homepage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Imuw6.png)

I have tried it to be done with callbacks of owl.carousel and slick carousel, but none of them work for me, if anybody having any idea on how to do this, that will be really appreciated.

**my code for slider is ->**

```
<?php $slides = $this->getMainCollection();?>

<div  class="homepage-slider">
    <div id="main-slider" class="owl-carousel owl-theme gray-dark-font white-btn-container">
        <?php foreach($slides as $slide): ?>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).$slide->getCollectionImg();?>" alt="<?php echo $slide->getCollectionName();?>">
            <div class="collection_option">
                <h2><?php echo $slide->getCollectionName();?></h2>
                <p><?php echo $slide->getCollectionDesc();?></p>
                <a href="<?php echo $slide->getUrl();?>" class="button">EXPLORE <?php echo $slide->getCollectionName();?></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php endforeach;?>
    </div>
</div>
```

**And jQuery is ->**

```
jQuery(function($){
   $(document).ready(function() {
       $('#main-slider').owlCarousel({
            singleItem : true,
            slideSpeed : 200,
            pagination: true,
            navigation: true,
            autoPlay:true,
            loop:true,
            responsiveRefreshRate : 200,
            transitionStyle : "fade",
            afterMove: function (elem) {
              var current = this.currentItem;
              var carousel = elem.find(".owl-item").eq(current).find(".item").attr('data-carousel');
             // $('.collection_wrapper').removeClass('hide-slide');
             // $(carousel).toggleClass('show-slide','hide-slide');
            },
        });
    });

});
```

**And for Carousel My code Is ->**

```
<?php $slides = $this->getMainCollection();?>

    <div class="collection_outer_wrapper" >
    <?php $i=0; foreach($slides as $slide): ?>

        <div class="collection_wrapper <?php echo $i==0 ? 'show-slide' : 'hide-slide'; ?>" id="collection_<?php echo $slide->getId();?>">
            <ul class="sliderItems">
                <li><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/product/1 (1).jpg') ?>" width="449.6px" /></li>

            </ul>    
            <div class="clearout"></div>
        </div>
    <?php $i++; endforeach;?>
    </div>
```

**And jQuery for carousel is->**

```
jQuery (function($){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.sliderItems').flexisel({
            visibleItems: 3,
            itemsToScroll: 1,         
            autoPlay: {
                enable: false,
                interval: 3000,
                pauseOnHover: true
            }
        }); 
    })

});
```

*I dont know what to do and how to do. so this code is messy.. please go through it.*

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post your code? HTML+JS?

Comment: @Roysh please review my edit. Thanks